# NoSuchMethodError for different method when invoking java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection()

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to follow [the quick Hello World for connecting a java client to Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html#I_want_to_get_started._Is_there_a_Phoenix_Hello_World).  My code is pretty similar to the example, main difference is the kerberos login info in my `getConnection()` string:

```
package com.demo.hbase;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class HBaseClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:myHadoopServer1,myHadoopServer2,myHadoopServer3:2181/hbase-secure:myPrinciple:/path/to/my/keytab.keytab");
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate("create table test (mykey integer not null primary key, mycolumn varchar)");
        stmt.executeUpdate("upsert into test values (1,'Hello')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("upsert into test values (2,'World!')");
        con.commit();

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from test");
        rset = statement.executeQuery();
        while (rset.next()) {
            System.out.println(rset.getString("mycolumn"));
        }
        statement.close();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

When running this I get an exception on the line containing `DriverManager.getConnection`, but the error is for not being able to find a method in the HBase library, which isn't even being explicitly called in this Hello World.  Furthermore, the method that its complaining about not existing definitely does exist!

Full text of the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;ZLjava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/security/User;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Connection;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.HConnectionFactory$HConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(HConnectionFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$400(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:267)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2523)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2499)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2499)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:255)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:147)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:221)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.demo.hbase.HBaseClient.main(HBaseClient.java:18)
```

I tried explicitly importing the ConnectionFactory class, but that didn't change anything.  I'm a little at a loss for how to troubleshoot this.  The ConnectionFactory class isn't explicitly used anywhere, [and ConnectionFactory.createConnection() definitely does exist](https://hbase.apache.org/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/ConnectionFactory.html).

Comment: You have to add all libs of the correct version to the classpath. Your error obviously indicates that there are different versions of the HBase API mixed up in the classpath

Comment: @AKSW looks like you were right, I had some imports in my maven with other hbase versions I was using before I switched to Phoenix.  I deleted my ~/.m2/repository/ folder and commented out the unneeded imports and it worked.  If you post this as an answer I'll accept it so you can get those sweet sweet internet points.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah, this happens quite often, especially with Maven. You can post it as an answer by yourself - and accept it.